# How can I find out the number ul elements in the path of a li element?

Tags: jquery

For example, I have the following html content, using jquery, how do I find out the number of ul element from the li text of a2? I'm sure closest method can accomplish this but how if you don't know in advance how many ul are there...

```
<ul id="ul_first">
     <li>a</li>
     <li>b</li>
     <li>c</li>
     <li>d</li>
     <li>c
              <ul id="ul_second">
                           <li>a2</li>   <------- From here, this li has two ul element
                           <li>b2</li>
                           <li>c2</li>
                           <li>d2</li>
              </ul>    
     </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents):

```
var numberOfULsContainingThisElement = $(this).parents('ul').length;
```

That assumes `this` is the DOM element of the `li` you pointed to (for instance, if you clicked on it, `this` in the click handler).

You wouldn't use `closest` because it stops at the first match. `parents` collects all ancestors that match the selector.

In your *specific* case (e.g., not in a click handler), that would be:

```
var numberOfULsContainingThisElement = $("#ul_second li").first().parents('ul').length;
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/odogir/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/odogir/1/edit)